# OpenCV python list append issue

Tags: python, opencv

when I tried to add images to list, the last updated image is added to all the list item.

How can I add separate images to outimages.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimage
import numpy as np
import time

in_image = cv2.imread("/home/vivek/Codes/Stackoverflow/face.jpg",-1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(in_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#find canny
cannyimg  = cv2.Canny(in_image,100,200)

#Contour
contours, hierarcy = cv2.findContours(cannyimg, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#create new image    
outimage = np.zeros(in_image.shape)


imgs = []


for a in range(0,5):
    cv2.drawContours(outimage, contours, a, (20,255,80), 3)
    imgs.append(outimage)

for a in range(0,5):
    cv2.imshow('outimg',imgs[a]
    cv2.waitKey(33)
```

the imgs have same image in all items.

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only created one image, and re-appended it to the list after each change.  If you want them to be distinct images, you need to make distinct images.